# Using JavaScript/jQuery to display an element's ID on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I been trying to figure this out, but I haven't yet.

I am building column in html of anchor tags and I would like to know the id of the one that has the mouse over it.

It should be simple, but seems like I hit a wall and I can't see how to solve this.

The problem I have is that the id that is display on the console is all the time the last id of the array. And instead of that I want to the id of the specific anchor.

Any suggestions are really welcome.

Here is my code:

```
//Anchor builder
var numberOf = flatParamDateArray.length;

for (i = 0; i < numberOf; i++) {
    var param2Slider = document.createElement("a");
    param2Slider.id = 'sliderAnchor' + i;
    sliderAnchorId = param2Slider.id;
    param2Slider.name = 'param2Slider';
    param2Slider.className = 'nav2Slider a';
    document.getElementById('nav2Slider').appendChild(param2Slider);
    $('.nav2Slider a').onmouseover = function () {
        console.log('flatParamDateArray index: ' + param2Slider.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's your html? Part of the problem is using plain JavaScript events with jQuery objects. It also looks far more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: I'm using this with a jquery plugin to make an animation with images. I already have an anchor column that works with one animation. But the user has the option two select two animations and so I am implementing an anchor column that controls both animations. That is why I create anchors from the 'numberOf' which is the amount of pictures from one animation. And I want to use the mouseover to call the images which correspond to the anchor id.

Comment: How does that tell me what your html looks like, show the relevant code.

Comment: @DavidThomas here is the relevant part where I add the column of anchor tags: 'code'<td><div id= 'slidesArea'></div></td><td style="position: absolute; right: 75px;">
            <div class='navSlider' id='navSlider'></div>
            <div class='navSlider' id='nav2Slider'></div>
        </td>'code'

Comment: @DavidThomas Anyway the question is already answered, thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Move this **out**, and **after** the for-loop:

```
$('.nav2Slider a').onmouseover = function () {
    console.log('flatParamDateArray index: '+param2Slider.id);
}
```

**2.** Change `onmouseover()` to `mouseover()`:

```
$('.nav2Slider a').mouseover(function() {
    console.log('flatParamDateArray index: '+param2Slider.id);
});
```

**3.** To get the ID, this is the code you need:

```
    console.log('flatParamDateArray index: '+ $(this).prop('id'));
```

**Bonus:**

Since you are dynamically adding links, you should use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function, to reduce the number of event handlers to one (as opposed to one per element):

```
$('.nav2Slider').on('mouseover', 'a', function() {
    console.log('flatParamDateArray index: '+ $(this).prop('id'));
});
```

Comment: Note that `on` can be used even without delegation. `$(".nav2Slider a").on("mouseover", function(){...})`

Comment: This fiddle doesn't measure the performance of the events being actually triggered. The cost of adding them is, IMO, negligible. I still agree delegation is often a good idea..

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `param2Slider` is global and the `for` loop changes the value on every loop. This means that after the loop is finished `param2Slider` just contains the last value.

Try this:

```
$('.nav2Slider a').on('onmouseover', function () {
    console.log('flatParamDateArray index: ' + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Edit: onmouseover... & of course you should move this snippet out of the loop

Comment: AvL thanks for your answer and for the explanation about why I was getting always the same value. I choose Samuel answers, because it has more detail and helped me to get a better idea about how solve the issue. And it had the .on bonus :)

Comment: That's fair because he explained it a lot better - and paid more attention in the first place ;-)